# Easy way to plot multiple line plots on same chart

Tags: excel, sas

Suppose I have a file arranged in the following format:

```
V1 V2 V3
A  Q1 1.3
A  Q2 2.3
A  Q3 4.1
B  Q1 5.1
B  Q2 0.4
B  Q3 0.9
C  Q1 1.0
C  Q2 0.4
.  .   .
.  .   .
.  .   .
.  .   .
```

This goes on for quite some time(I have 1000 categories). What is an easy way in excel or sas to plot multiple line charts on the same graph where one line plot is defined by a category? So for example, all the points mapping to A will represent one line chart. V1 is the category, V2 is time, and V3 are the particular values. It would be easy if each category was defined in a particular column but in this dataset, all categories are in one column.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sgplot data=data1;
  vline v2 / v3 group=v1;
run;
```

To limit the groups seen include a where statement in parentheses next to the data statement;

```
proc sgplot data=data1(where=(v1 in ('A','B','C')));
  vline v2 / v3 group=v1;
run;
```